# REPL Driven Development in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, emacs, ecmascript-6, read-eval-print-loop

In languages like `Clojure` and `Scheme` I do really enjoy writing code in REPL-driven mode, when you write a piece of code in an editor (`Emacs` in my case), send it to your REPL, play with it then go back to an editor, fix found issues and send code to REPL again.

I tried to do the same with `Node.js`, and it kind of works if I limit myself to usage of `ES5` syntax only. But if I use `ES6` features like `const`, `let` and `class`, I expectedly get errors on re-evaluation of my declarations:

```
> let foo = 1;
> let foo = 2;
TypeError: Identifier 'foo' has already been declared
```

Is there any `Node.js REPL` params, or maybe patched `REPLs`, or even some magical `Emacs` mode which will purge existing declarations when I re-evaluate my code? So that I will be able to write `Node.js` code this way without the need to constantly think about which syntax I am using and/or the need to restart `REPL` manually on each re-evaluation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using `nodejs-repl`, you can eval (`M-:`) the following code :

```
(with-current-buffer "*nodejs*" 
  (setq kill-buffer-query-functions (delq 'process-kill-buffer-query-function kill-buffer-query-functions))
  (kill-process nil comint-ptyp) 
  (kill-buffer-and-window) 
  (run-with-timer 0.01 nil (lambda () (nodejs-repl))
))
```

This is not an optimal solution, but here's how it works :

- It evals emacs lisp code in the current buffer
- It kills the function that ask you if you want to kill the window (confirmation in the minibuffer)
- It stops the process that allows the communication between nodejs and emacs, so it kills nodejs process (comint-ptyp)
- It re-runs `nodejs-repl`

If you want to run it with another REPL, just change the buffer name and the command to 're-run'.

Hope it helps,

Best regards

### EDIT

Here's a more suitable solution, add this to your `.emacs` or to the `nodejs-repl.el` :

```
(defun nodejs-repl-restart ()
  "restart the nodejs REPL"
  (interactive)
  (defvar nodejs-repl-code
    (concat "process.stdout.columns = %d;" "require('repl').start('%s', null, null, true, false)"))
  (with-current-buffer "*nodejs*"
    (kill-process nil comint-ptyp)
    (run-with-timer 0.01 nil (lambda ()
                  (setq nodejs-repl-prompt-re (format nodejs-repl-prompt-re-format nodejs-repl-prompt nodejs-repl-prompt))
                  (with-current-buffer "*nodejs*"
                (apply 'make-comint nodejs-repl-process-name nodejs-repl-command nil `("-e" ,(format nodejs-repl-code (window-width) nodejs-repl-prompt)))
                (nodejs-repl-mode) (erase-buffer) )))))
```

It almost does the same, but it doesn't kill the buffer and it erase it.

Answer (score 1):

Node.js has good basis for REPL driven development. Multiple factors for approving it:

- JavaScript is interpreted language and supports `eval`
- Ability to write statefull programs and change this state in some way
- Ability to connect to Node.js process via [inspect](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v19.x/docs/api/cli.html#--inspecthostport) protocol and execute arbitrary code, that can change internal state of program

ClojureScript projects, like [nbb](https://github.com/babashka/nbb) uses this possibilities for successful REPL driven development on Node.js directly. Also exists another tools, that allow to feel Clojure like REPL driven development, but using JavaScript/TypeScript:

- [node-remote-repl](https://github.com/darky/node-remote-repl) - command line tool for executing arbitrary file code on remote (likely localhost) Node.js process via [inspect](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v19.x/docs/api/cli.html#--inspecthostport) protocol. This command line tool can be integrated with any IDE, VSCode example provided. This project inspired by Clojure nREPL.
- [repl-ns](https://github.com/darky/repl-ns) - Implementation of namespace, inspired by Clojure namespace directly, which allows to write REPL driven development friendly code, with program state preserving by default.

[node-remote-repl](https://github.com/darky/node-remote-repl) + [repl-ns](https://github.com/darky/repl-ns) inspired by Clojure and allows to feel Clojure way of RDD in Node.js using JavaScript/TypeScript. By the way, RDD excellent for TUI developing, because it stateful often. [ytdl-tui](https://github.com/darky/ytdl-tui) - TUI, which written totally using RDD and tools, mentioned above, feel free to use it as source of inspiration.

Few words about native Node.js REPL. I think it's toy tool, which allows to execute little snippets of code, but no good for big serious project.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote [Replete](https://github.com/jamesdiacono/Replete), an evaluator for JavaScript modules. It supports import statements, and evaluates code in the browser, Node.js and Deno. There is an Emacs plugin, among others.

[image: Demo of Replete]